# Perl and DBD::Oracle - how many rows available to fetch? RowsInCache?

Tags: oracle, perl, dbi

I have a perl application that executes a SELECT against an Oracle database using DBD::Oracle.

I'd then like to check if any rows were returned, and branch based on that.

DBD::Oracle's rows() method returns -1 for SELECTs (according the perldoc and my testing), so what I'd do for MySQL won't work.

The perldoc mentions RowsInCache ("Returns the number of un-fetched rows in the cache for selects"), but trying to call or examine that from either my database or statement handle doesn't work.  E.g.:

```
if ( $sth->RowsInCache > 0 )
if ( $sth::RowsInCache > 0 ) 
if ( $dbh->RowsInCache > 0 )
if ( $dbh::RowsInCache > 0 )
```

I get either "Can't locate object method" or "Use of uninitialized value".  Wrong syntax on my part?

I'm aware of a couple ways off accomplishing what I want:

1. First do a SELECT COUNT, look at the number of rows, and then do the real SELECT.  But this is obviously extra work for the DB.
2. If you call

   $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref;

Then $row will be undefined if there are no rows and you can test that.  But then if your intent is something like this...

```
$sth->execute($some_bind);
while ( $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
```

...you have to either include some goofy logic to handle the fact that you've already fetched the first row to test if there are rows, or do something like this:

```
$sth->execute($some_bind);
$got_some_rows = 0;
while ( $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    $got_some_rows = 1;
    # other stuff
}
$sth->finish;
if ( $got_some_rows == 0 ) {
```

...which is not the end of the world but....if just seems like there should be some easy way to say "hey database, do you have any rows for me"?

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `$sth->{'RowsInCache'}`? That's the usual convention for DBD attributes, but I haven't used the Oracle one specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sth->RowsInCache;   # Wrong.  Method call for non-existent method.

$sth::RowsInCache;   # Wrong.  Looking for a variable $RowsInCache in package `sth'

$sth->{RowsInCache}  # Right.  RowsInCache is an attribute accessed as hashref element.
```

However, given what you want to do, this might seems better:

```
...
$sth->execute;
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  do_stuff_with($row);
}
if ($sth->rows == 0) {
  handle_the_case_where_there_were_no_results();
}
...
```

Generally, a DBI driver can only guarantee that `rows()` will be sensible *after* all rows have been fetched, but that applies to your case here.

Comment: Thank you!

Interestingly, for DBD::mysql, rows() will immediately return the number of rows that SELECT found.  You can call execute() on the statement handle and rows() on the very next line and get the right number, and it doesn't change due to subsequent fetchrow_hashrefs.

Comment: @raindog308, yes, but you'll see different behavior there, I think, if you change the default [`mysql_use_result`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#mysql_use_result) to true.